# What do the different ECS stop times mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

From
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Task.html there are multiple "stop" times for a task

> stoppedAt
>
> The Unix timestamp for when the task was stopped (the task transitioned from the RUNNING state to the STOPPED state).

and

> stoppingAt
>
> The Unix timestamp for when the task stops (transitions from the RUNNING state to STOPPED).

and

> executionStoppedAt
>
> The Unix timestamp for when the task execution stopped.

These descriptions seem very similar to me. What do they each mean? Specifically

- What is the difference between `stoppedAt` and `stoppingAt`?
- What does it mean for a task execution to stop, and how(/why?) is that different to `stoppedAt` or `stoppingAt`?
- Up to which time is the task billed for?

---

As an examples, calling `describe-tasks` for a recently stopped task gives:

```
"executionStoppedAt": 1568462761.0,
"stoppingAt":         1568462761.499,
"stoppedAt":          1568462817.635,
```

and another task gives

```
"executionStoppedAt": 1568464247.0,
"stoppingAt":         1568464246.39,
"stoppedAt":          1568464300.417,
```

which interestingly shows that the various times are not always in the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-lifecycle.html) of ECS task it contains the complete cycle before stoping the task as the ECS agent involves between this life cycle.

[image]

**Lifecycle States**
The following are descriptions of each of the task lifecycle states.

**PROVISIONING**

> Amazon ECS has to perform additional steps before the task is
>   launched. For example, for tasks that use the awsvpc network mode, the
>   elastic network interface needs to be provisioned.

**PENDING**

> This is a transition state where Amazon ECS is waiting on the
>   container agent to take further action.

**ACTIVATING**

> Amazon ECS has to perform additional steps after the task is launched
>   but before the task can transition to the RUNNING state. For example,
>   for tasks that have service discovery configured, the service
>   discovery resources must be created. For tasks that are part of a
>   service that is configured to use multiple Elastic Load Balancing
>   target groups, the target group registration occurs during this state.

**RUNNING**

> The task is successfully running.

**DEACTIVATING**

> Amazon ECS has to perform additional steps before the task is stopped.
>   For example, for tasks that are part of a service that is configured
>   to use multiple Elastic Load Balancing target groups, the target group
>   deregistration occurs during this state.

**STOPPING**

> This is a transition state where Amazon ECS is waiting on the
>   container agent to take further action.

**DEPROVISIONING**

> Amazon ECS has to perform additional steps after the task has stopped
>   but before the task transitions to the STOPPED state. For example, for
>   tasks that use the awsvpc network mode, the elastic network interface
>   needs to be detached and deleted.

**STOPPED**

> The task has been successfully stopped.

Comment: This helps with the difference between `stoppingAt` and `stoppedAt`, but do you have any guidance on `executionStoppedAt`, and why it is sometimes before `stoppingAt` and sometimes after?

Comment: When StopTask is called on a task, the equivalent of docker stop is issued to the containers running in the task. This results in a SIGTERM value and a default 30-second timeout, after which the SIGKILL value is sent and the containers are forcibly stopped. If the container handles the SIGTERM value gracefully and exits within 30 seconds from receiving it, no SIGKILL value is sent.

Comment: So it might be the case the container not stoped in desired timeout. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_StopTask.html